# How to set attributes to an element in angular on clicking?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and need help from you guys for my below requirement:

I have two anchor elements with the click event attached to both. What I want to do is that on clicking this anchor element, I want to set the attribute value of **data-wizard-state** to **current** and remove from the other anchor element.

```
 <a
        class="wizard-step"
        href="javascript:;"
        data-wizard-type="step"
        [attr.data-wizard-state]="tabClass"
        (click)="showtabcontent()"
      >Link 1</a>

 <a
            class="wizard-step"
            href="javascript:;"
            data-wizard-type="step"
            [attr.data-wizard-state]="tabClass"
            (click)="showtabcontent()"
          >Link 2</a>
```

**TS code:**

```
 showtabcontent() {
this.tabClass='current';}
```

Comment: ahmed i updated the answer for dynamic links.

Comment: Thanks Aakash for the solution

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b2rzma?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML :-

```
<a #a1 class="wizard-step" href="javascript:;" data-wizard-type="step"
  (click)="showtabcontent(a1,a2)">Link 1</a>

<a #a2 class="wizard-step" href="javascript:;" data-wizard-type="step" 
  (click)="showtabcontent(a2,a1)">Link 2</a>
```

Typescript :-

```
export class AppComponent {
  tabClass = 'current';

  showtabcontent(
    currentLink: HTMLAnchorElement,
    previousLink: HTMLAnchorElement
  ): void {
    currentLink.dataset.wizardState = this.tabClass;
    delete previousLink.dataset.wizardState;
  }
}
```

OR if dynamic anchors :-

HTML :-

```
<a *ngFor="let a of links; let i= index" #link class="wizard-step" href="javascript:;" data-wizard-type="step"
  (click)="showtabcontent(link)">Link {{i}}</a>
```

TS :-

```
import { Component, ElementRef, QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';  
export class AppComponent {
  tabClass = 'current';
  links = [1, 2, 3];
  @ViewChildren('link', { read: ElementRef }) anchors: QueryList<
    ElementRef<HTMLAnchorElement>
  >;
  showtabcontent(currentLink: HTMLAnchorElement): void {
    this.anchors.forEach(anchor => {
      console.log(anchor);
      delete anchor.nativeElement.dataset.wizardState;
    });
    currentLink.dataset.wizardState = this.tabClass;
  }
}
```

Working Stackblitz :-

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b2rzma?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Like any other front-end programing tools, each tag/element needs to have an identification so we know who is who, and more importantly we can refer to it to do something.

Step 1, give them an ID, in Angular you can denote it with a prefix `#`, for example:

```
<a #ID1 attr.data-wizard-state="tabClass" ... (click)="showtabcontent('1')">Link 1</a>
<a #ID2 attr.data-wizard-state="tabClass" ... (click)="showtabcontent()">Link 2</a>
```

In TS, you need to refer to it in order to do something

```
import { ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2, ... } from '@angular/core';
@ViewChild("ID1")
public ID1: ElementRef;
@ViewChild("ID2")
public ID2: ElementRef;
// above enable us to manipulate the 2 <a>
constructor(...)
showtabcontent(...)
{
  if (condition)
  {
    this.ID1.nativeElement.... // do whatever you want here
    this.ID2.nativeElement....
  }
}
```

Now, if your app is internal, you trust all user won't do any harm, above is good enough. Otherwise

Step 2, here is why we import `Renderer2` for:

```
constructor(public rd: Renderer2){...}
showtabcontent(...)
{
  if (condition)
  {
    this.rd.setAttribute(this.ID1.nativeElement, "attr.data-wizard-state", "any value");
    this.rd.setAttribute(this.ID2.nativeElement, "attr.data-wizard-state", "any value or empty");
  }
}
```

There could be other ways to achieve what you're looking for, but this's good enough.